# How to fit an image in a button in jquerymobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to modify a button in order to show an image that fits its size, [the source code here](http://jsfiddle.net/yWkGR/40/)

```
.ui-icon-myimg {
background: url(http://www.metalunderground.pt/download/file.php?avatar=2015_1331126201.jpg) no-repeat;}
```

(I had to put this bit of css here because otherwise I am unable to link jsfiddle)

Why I can see only the orange circle? I've tried on and on modifying widths and heights but I cannot find any working way.

Help me please!

Thanks

Comment: You want to cover the whole button or what? like this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/yWkGR/49/ or replace the icon?

Comment: yes exactly. I've found another way to do this without css: putting 'style="height: 55px; width: 55px; background: url(url_to_img) no-repeat'  directly in the html. But this makes the button lose things like changing color on mouse over and so on.

Comment: oohh, you got it! but I want to lose the "+" icon too.

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/yWkGR/50/

Comment: seems fine but... I've noticed that in this way ALL the buttons will have the same image...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/UTZp2/ i used `.mybtn`

Comment: dude, you won the whole world ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the css Like :

```
.ui-controlgroup .ui-btn-icon-notext .ui-btn-inner .ui-icon {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
left: 45%;
top: 40%;
margin: -9px -9px 0 0;
}

.ui-btn-inner {
height: 100% !important;
padding: .55em 11px .5em 11px;
}

.ui-controlgroup-controls li a {
position: relative !important;
}
```

See this Fiddle :
http://jsfiddle.net/yWkGR/52/

I have modified my code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add dimensions (`width:`, `height:`). Elements have no idea how big their background images are.

Answer (score 1):

To apply changes on specific buttons, give them classes and then override properties of `ui-btn`.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/UTZp2/)**

```
.mybtn .ui-btn {
  background: url(image.jpg) center no-repeat;
}
```

And then remove icon, using jQuery.

```
$('.mybtn span.ui-icon').removeClass('ui-icon ui-icon-shadow');
```

Answer (score 0):

first off the picture is too large for the icon. You have to put in the sizes for the icon image and the box. Your span class below has to have the sizes right.

```
.ui-icon ui-icon-myimg ui-icon-shadow{
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px; // or whatever size the icon is 
}
```

You need to change your CSS sheets to this:

```
.ui-btn-inner {
  height: 120px;
  padding: 0.55em 11px 0.5em;
  width: 120px;
}

.ui-icon {
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
}
```

If you right click over the icon in firebug and switch out the code (erasing padding and margins ) your image fits perfect.

Comment: you're right, the image is too big but the problem isn't there (I've just enlarged the button to 120x120) and the image is still that little (even adding your css)  http://jsfiddle.net/yWkGR/45/

Comment: Have you tried it with jsfiddle? That does not seem to work... I have already tried out modifying elements in firebug, and it does work. But  when you render the page, there are lots of css properties overwritten by jquerymobile

Comment: I'd have to see all the code then to see what is being overwritten

Comment: I guess what I meant is the code in Jsfiddle is mixed with yours. So if everything was in the CSS spot and HTML spot I could copy it and mess around with it, but it isn't. There is only a portion of it there and I'm not sure which is yours and which is jsfiddle's.

Comment: umh... the code that you see in jsfiddle is mine. Plus the jquerymobile library that is selected in the left column

Comment: It is all in your CSS coding so whether you have a file written out that holds your CSS codes or if it is implemented in the jQuery or javascript, that is what you need to change. You just have to find out where that code is.